# What is the proper MVVM way to place a collection of symbols on a map?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF Window with a Canvas that is used to show a terrain map. I would like to place symbols on this map according to an `IEnumerable<MapSymbolDefinition>` where `MapSymbolDefinition` is defined as follows:

```
public class MapSymbolDefinition
{
  string SymbolFileName { get; set; }
  int XLocation { get; set; }
  int YLocation { get; set; }
}
```

All symbols are stored in the Symbols folder of my project, so the path to any symbol would be [ProjectFolder]/Symbols/SymbolFileName.bmp.

Any thoughts on how I can set this up so I don't have to populate a bunch of Image objects manually in the code-behind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` with customized `ItemsPanel`, `ItemContainerStyle` and `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MapSymbols}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YLocation}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XLocation}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MapSymbolDefinition}">
            <Image Source="{Binding SymbolFileName, Converter={StaticResource ImageNameConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Update after comments**: You can define an `ItemTemplate` to provide the visual tree for each item in the collection. In this case I used a converter to convert the `SymbolFileName` property to an image, but you could equally define a separate property on your `MapSymbolDefinition` class that yields the full path. The latter approach is more in line with MVVM best practices.

Comment: Hi, Kent. I just edited my question because I think was unclear about one thing: the enumeration actually contains *definitions* of map symbols (not the symbols themselves). So, in your example, the ItemsSource is not being bound to the actual Image objects I want to show. Is there some way to include a DataTemplate that converts from SymbolFileName to `<Image Source="{Path=SymbolFileName}"`? Thanks.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, what @sixlettervariables said :)

Comment: @DanThMan: that code looks perfect actually (minus not saying Binding). `<Image Source="{Binding SymbolFileName}" />` in the `DataTemplate` is all you need. The confusing part Kent handled which is having the `ItemContainerStyle` do the `Canvas` offsets.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF way: Use DataTemplates and a ListBox and converters and ....  Check out [this example](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=40).

The quick way: Just do it in the code-behind and call your view a control.